# Disable Cookieless Session .Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

We previously had cookieless session enabled on our application. We have disabled this and gone to session cookies however we are having a problem. Users who had the session ID in their URL as a bookmark are still able to navigate to the site with the session id in the url. I have set  it to not regenerate expired sessions but it is still allowing it anyways. It also ends up creating a session cookie in addition and then we are getting random session loss. I've come up with a few wonky workarounds like stripping it out using a URL rewrite and stripping it out via javascript but this seems bad. Is there anything built in that I am missing that can help with this? Not that it should matter for this but I will add we are using state server.

Comment: URL rewrite is a good solution. Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URL rewrite is a good solution to this.

However if you would like users to update their bookmarks, (so you can eventually retire the URL rewrite) you might consider having your URL rewrite send them to a page telling them so:

- Oops! That link doesn't work.

And then giving them the usual options to log in etc.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for a solution that won't require users to update their bookmarks I was able to use the following in my Global.asax `Application_BeginRequest`:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (CookielessValuesExist()) {
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.OriginalString, true);
    }
}

private bool CookielessValuesExist() {
    string cookieless = Request.Params["HTTP_ASPFILTERSESSIONID"];
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookieless)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```